# SSRS text field return blank for comma separated values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a data set in my report which has a field which contains values like this:

```
12, 13, 16
```

When I am trying to disply this field in report then this field is blank.

I tried

```
=JOIN(Fields!ABC.Value, ",")
```

but then it throws `#Error` for the values in the report.

Comment: are you sure there are no carriage returns or similar at the start of the field? 
If you are just trying to display the text as it comes from the dataset then there should be no need to do anything.

Comment: Hey @AlanSchofield  thanks for the reply ..i am trying to show the value as it comes from the sql Query but then this perticular Field has blank rather than the values .. i am not getting the point. in sql query i am getting the comma seperated values#

Answer (score 0):

i got the Solution i returned the list from sql  as ';' seperated instead of ',' sepearted. And the values got displayed :). In case any one strugling with the same.